# Marzipano cannot integrate with data grabbed from Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, marzipano

I have some questions regarding using data from the API endpoint and putting them into the panorama setting by marzipano site. When I try to connect to the local host, it always gives me a black screen with some weird bugs.
The

bug

[image: 1]

Below is the bug in the file index.js.

```js
// Detect desktop or mobile mode.
  if (window.matchMedia) {
    var setMode = function() {
      if (mql.matches) {
        document.body.classList.remove('desktop');
        document.body.classList.add('mobile');
      } else {
      
     // Here is the bug document.body.classList.remove('mobile');
     // VM1193 index.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read 
     // properties of null (reading 'classList')
     // at setMode (VM1193 index.js:40:23)
     // at VM1193 index.js:45:5
     // at VM1193 index.js:392:3

        document.body.classList.remove('mobile');
        document.body.classList.add('desktop');
      }
    };
    var mql = matchMedia("(max-width: 500px), (max-height: 500px)");
    setMode();
    mql.addListener(setMode);
  } else {
    document.body.classList.add('desktop');
  }
```

```js
// Viewer options.
  var viewerOpts = {
    controls: {
    // Here is the bug data.settings.mouseViewMode
    // index.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of
    // undefined (reading 'settings')
    // at index.js:66:27
    // at index.js:392:3
      mouseViewMode: data.settings.mouseViewMode
    }
  };
```

The index.js file is generated by Marzipano, and I did not change any codes inside. The only file I changed is the data.js file. When I did not use the fetch API to get the data from the website, it works totally fine. But if I add the statement "import fetch from 'node-fetch';", it will crash.

Below is the code how I tried to get data from the web.

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
async function getUser(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    //console.log(response);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    const result = await response.json();
    let data1 = await result[result.length-1]['data1'];
    return {
      'data1': data1,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
async function update_API(){
  let data = await getUser(API_url);
  var APP_DATA = {
    "scenes": [
      {
        "id": "some image id",
        "name": "image name",
        "levels": [
          {
            "tileSize": 256,
            "size": 256,
            "fallbackOnly": true
          },
          {
            "tileSize": 512,
            "size": 512
          },
          {
            "tileSize": 512,
            "size": 1024
          },
          {
            "tileSize": 512,
            "size": 2048
          }
        ],
        "faceSize": 1520,
        "initialViewParameters": {
          "pitch": 0,
          "yaw": 0,
          "fov": 1.5707963267948966
        },
        "linkHotspots": [
          {
            "yaw": -2.771335362922997,
            "pitch": 0.5852719406432207,
            "rotation": 3.141592653589793,
            "target": "1-img_20220708_192930_00_merged"
          }
        ],
        "infoHotspots": [
          {
            "yaw": -2.788116932948755,
            "pitch": 0.2275120663788961,
            "title": "Example 1",
            "text": "<div>[data 1] " + data1
          }
        ]
      }
      ],
      "name": "Trial 1",
  "settings": {
    "mouseViewMode": "drag",
    "autorotateEnabled": true,
    "fullscreenButton": true,
    "viewControlButtons": true
  }
};
```

I tried to search for a solution but can't. I am wondering if I used it incorrectly or there should be some issue between Marzipano site and Fetch API?

---Edit for HTML code---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project name</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" />
<style> @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; } </style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/reset.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="module" src="data.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="multiple-scenes ">

<div id="pano"></div>

<div id="sceneList">
  <ul class="scenes">
    
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="scene" data-id="image file">
        <li class="text">data 1</li>
      </a>    
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="titleBar">
  <h1 class="sceneName"></h1>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="autorotateToggle">
  <img class="icon off" src="img/play.png">
  <img class="icon on" src="img/pause.png">
</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="fullscreenToggle">
  <img class="icon off" src="img/fullscreen.png">
  <img class="icon on" src="img/windowed.png">
</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="sceneListToggle">
  <img class="icon off" src="img/expand.png">
  <img class="icon on" src="img/collapse.png">
</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewUp" class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-1">
  <img class="icon" src="img/up.png">
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewDown" class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-2">
  <img class="icon" src="img/down.png">
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewLeft" class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-3">
  <img class="icon" src="img/left.png">
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewRight" class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-4">
  <img class="icon" src="img/right.png">
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewIn" class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-5">
  <img class="icon" src="img/plus.png">
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewOut" class="viewControlButton viewControlButton-6">
  <img class="icon" src="img/minus.png">
</a>

<script src="vendor/screenfull.min.js" ></script>
<script src="vendor/bowser.min.js" ></script>
<script src="vendor/marzipano.js" ></script>

<script type="module" src="data.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot use `node-fetch` in the browser. Remove `import fetch from 'node-fetch';`

Comment: Where in your HTML are you putting the `index.js` `<script>` tag?

Comment: I got it! Will remove it.

Comment: I put it like <script src="index.js"></script>. Is it correct (it is set by the Marzipano site too)?

Comment: Yes, but where in the HTML document is it?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question and included the HTML code inside. Hope this can make the question clear.